Comparative Statics - Capital Augmenting Technological Change
I am reading the article by Acemoglu and Restrepo (AEA Papers and Proceedings, 2018) and have encountered some difficulties deriving equation (1). I hope you can help me work through it.
The aggregate output is given by
\begin{equation}
Y = F(A_K K, A_L L)
\end{equation}
where $K$ denotes capital, $L$ represents labor, and $A_K$ and $A_L$ denote capital-augmenting and labor-augmenting technology, respectively. The production function $F$ is assumed to be continuously differentiable, concave, and to exhibit constant returns to scale.
Let $F_K$ and $F_L$ denote the marginal products of capital and labor, respectively.
Assuming a competitive labor market, the wage rate $W$ must satisfy
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial Y}{\partial L} = W \quad \text{, i.e.,} \quad W = A_L F_L(A_K K, A_L L)
\end{equation}
The labor share in national income is denoted by
\begin{equation}
s_L = \frac{WL}{Y}
\end{equation}
and the capital share is $s_K = 1 - s_L$.
The article then claims that
\begin{equation}
\frac{d \ln W}{d \ln A_K} = \frac{s_K}{\epsilon_{KL}}
\end{equation}
where $\epsilon_{KL} = - \frac{d \ln (K/L)}{d \ln (F_K/F_L)}$ is the elasticity of substitution between capital and labor.
I attempted to derive the result $\frac{d \ln W}{d \ln A_K} = \frac{s_K}{\epsilon_{KL}}$ as follows:
First, note that $\ln W = \ln A_L + \ln F_L(A_K K, A_L L)$. Therefore,
\begin{equation}
\frac{d \ln W}{d \ln A_K} = \frac{\frac{d W}{W}}{\frac{d A_K}{A_K}} = \frac{d W}{d A_K} \cdot \frac{A_K}{W} 
\end{equation}
Substituting $W = A_L F_L$ into the equation, we have
\begin{equation}
\frac{d \ln W}{d \ln A_K} = A_L \cdot \frac{\partial F_L}{\partial (A_K K)} \cdot \frac{\partial (A_K K)}{\partial A_K} \cdot \frac{A_K}{A_L F_L} 
\end{equation}
This simplifies to:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d \ln W}{d \ln A_K} = \frac{A_K K}{F_L} \cdot \frac{\partial F_L}{\partial (A_K K)} 
\end{equation}
To make further progress, I attempted to multiply and divide by $Y$, resulting in:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d \ln W}{d \ln A_K} = \frac{s_K Y}{F_L} \cdot \frac{\partial F_L}{\partial (A_K K)} 
\end{equation}
However, I am struggling to complete the derivation and arrive at the final equation given in the paper. Could someone help me bridge the gap?

There is a mistake at the end of your working. The capital share is $s_K=\frac{RK}{Y}=\frac{A_K F_K K}{Y}$, not $\frac{A_K K}{Y}$. Fixing this small mistake, your final expression is (with obvious arguments suppressed), $$\frac{d \ln W}{d \ln A_K}=s_K \frac{Y}{F_K F_L} \frac{\partial F_L}{\partial A_K K}= s_K \frac{F F_{KL}}{F_K F_L}$$
For the final step, one wants to show that $\frac{1}{\varepsilon_{KL}}=\frac{F(A_K K, A_L L) F_{LK}(A_K K, A_LL)}{F_K(A_K K, A_L L) F_L(A_K K, A_L L)}$
To this end, since $F$ is homogeneous of degree 1, its partial derivatives are homogeneous of degree 0. So, $$\begin{align*} \ln (F_K/F_L) &=\ln \left(F_K\left(1,\frac{A_L L}{A_K K}\right)\right)-\ln \left(F_L\left(\frac{A_K K}{A_L L},1\right)\right) \\
&=\ln \left(F_K\left(1,\frac{A_L }{A_K}\exp\{-\ln(K/L)\}\right)\right)-\ln \left(F_L\left(\frac{A_K}{A_L}\exp\{\ln(K/L)\},1\right)\right) \end{align*}$$
Whence, $$\frac{d \ln (F_K/F_L)}{d \ln (K/L)}=-\frac{1}{F_K}\frac{A_L L}{A_K K}F_{KL}\left(1,\frac{A_L L}{A_K K}\right)-\frac{1}{F_L}\frac{A_K K}{A_L L}F_{KL}\left(\frac{A_K K}{A_L L},1\right)$$
Since $F$ is homogeneous of degree 1, $F_{KL}$ is homogenous of degree -1, so our expression simplifies to $$\begin{align*}\frac{d \ln (F_K/F_L)}{d \ln (K/L)}&=-\frac{1}{F_K(A_K K,A_L L)}\frac{A_L L}{A_K K}F_{KL}\left(1,\frac{A_L L}{A_K K}\right)-\frac{1}{F_L(A_K K,A_L L)}\frac{A_K K}{A_L L}F_{KL}\left(\frac{A_K K}{A_L L},1\right) \\
&=-\frac{1}{F_K}A_L LF_{KL}\left(A_K K,A_L L\right)-\frac{1}{F_L}A_K KF_{KL}\left(A_K K,A_L L\right) \\
&=- \frac{F_{KL}\left(A_K K,A_L L\right)}{F_K(A_K K,A_L L)F_L(A_K K,A_L L)}\left[A_L L F_L(A_K K,A_L L)+A_KKF_K(A_K K,A_L L)\right] \\
&=-\frac{F_{KL}\left(A_K K,A_L L\right)F(A_K K,A_L L)}{F_K(A_K K,A_L L)F_L(A_K K,A_L L)} \end{align*}$$
Where I have used Euler's theorem in the final line.
Hence, $$\frac{1}{\varepsilon_{KL}}=-\frac{d \ln (F_K/F_L)}{d\ln (K/L)}=\frac{F(A_K K, A_L L) F_{LK}(A_K K, A_LL)}{F_K(A_K K, A_L L) F_L(A_K K, A_L L)}$$ and the result follows.

Thank you for your answer. Could you please clarify some of the notation? In the first line, you define
$F_{KL} \equiv \frac{\partial F_L}{\partial (A_K K)}$,
but then when you compute
$\frac{d \ln \left(\frac{F_K}{F_L}\right)}{d \left(\frac{K}{L}\right)}$,
it seems that
$F_{KL} \equiv \frac{\partial F_K}{\partial \left(\frac{K}{L}\right)}$.
What am I missing?

@Dimitru Those are cross partial derivatives. By $F_{KL}$ I mean the function obtained by differentiating $F$ with respect to $K$ and then with respect to $L$ (or the other way around). The notations $\frac{\partial F_L}{\partial (A_K K)}$ or $\frac{\partial F_K}{\partial (K/L)}$ are confusing since they don't tell us which argument the derivatives are taken with respect to, nor what the arguments are. That is why I explicitly wrote out the arguments of the functions throughout, since these do matter for the derivation.

I got it. There was I typo when you defined the elasticity of substitution (the log before $K/L$ was missing). Let me make all the computations and I'm sure they will work. After that, I will vote the answer. Thanks
